# symbian C++ descriptor class

Tags: c++, class, symbian, descriptor

why we cannot instantiate descriptor base class(TDesc)???

Answer (score 1):

Because it is an effectively abstract base class. Instances cann't be created for abstract classes.

Comment: This class cannot be instantiated as it is intended to form part of a class hierarchy.can you plz tell me what this line exactly means.

Comment: `it is intended to form part of a class hierarchy` - which means it (an object to it) cann't independently exist. It is a part of it's derived class instantiation.